# Go TCPConn not writing out data until connection is closed

Tags: go, tcp

I'm writing a "binary echo server" and I've tried several ways to continuously read binary data from a connection and echo that data back, and for whatever reason upon writing the data, it's not making it to the other side until the connection is closed.  Here is the handler method for the connection. As you can see I'm trying to read byte by byte (after several other attempts using io.Copy() failed.

```
func handle_relay_connection(instance *ServerInstance, conn *net.TCPConn) {
    var err error
    var b byte

    defer conn.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)

    for run_loop := true; run_loop; {
            b, err = reader.ReadByte()

            if err != nil {
                    if err != io.EOF {
                            logError("Problem reading data from connection %s: %v", instance.address, err)
                    } else {
                            logWarning("Client %s ended connection: %v", instance.address, err)
                    }

                    run_loop = false
            }
            writer.WriteByte(b)
            writer.Flush()
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. Whether it's `io.Copy` directly to the `*TCPConn`, or this byte-by-byte example, you are writing to the connection immediately. It's either being being buffered by your OS, or on the client side.

Comment: instead of `for run_loop := true; run_loop; {}` you can run simple `for {}`; net.TCPConn implements Read() and Write(), do you really need to wrap it with bufio?

Comment: I don't technically need a bufio, but I've gone through quite a few iterations trying to get this working.

Comment: Your writer.WriteByte(b) seems to be outside the loop...